# Windows Application Java Servlet Parameter Passing

Tags: c#, java, javascript, .net, windows

How to pass parameters from C#/.Net Windows Application to Java Servlet? One more thing to add here is that we cant touch the Java Servlet code.

Comment: I haven't worked on C#/.NET , but I believe there must be an option to post data to a URL , you can specify the java servlet URL and post your data to it. Editing it to add this snippet I found http://blog.brezovsky.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your java servlet is deployed in some container like Tomcat server. The easiest way to pass parameter to any web application is **through query string**.

**Assuming that**

- Servlet is deployed on a tomcat server (or any other container)
- The tomcat server is running on machine say mymachine and listening to port 8080
- The servlet is accessible via the following URL

  http://mymachine:8080/myapp/myservlet

Now to pass parameter (say param1 and param2) to it you can invoke following URL

http://mymachine:8080/myapp/myservlet?parame1=value1&param2=value2

Use the following C# code to invoke this servlet

```
HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create("http://mymachine:8080/myapp/myservlet?parame1=value1&param2=value2");

// execute the request
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try xml.

Serialize the data and then parse at the other end.

It may give you lag. But can work !